# Random number getting printed in the last position while inputting and array and then printing it after sorting

Tags: c++, sorting, swap

```
#include<bits/stdc++.h>
using namespace std;

int main(){

long int t;
cin>>t;
while(t--){
long int n;
cin>>n;
long long int arr[n];
for(long int i=0;i<n;i++)
    cin>>arr[i];
sort(arr,arr+n);

for(int i=1;i<n;i++)
    if(i%2!=0)
        swap(arr[i],arr[i+1]);

for(int i=0;i<n;i++)
    if(i!=n-1)
    cout<<arr[i]<<" ";
    else
        cout<<arr[i];
cout<<endl;
}
return 0;
}
```

My intention is to convert the input array to the following pattern:
A[i] ≤ A[i+1] if i is even.
A[i] ≥ A[i+1] if i is odd.

1 ≤ n ≤ 100000 
1 ≤ Arr[i] ≤ 10^9

[image: Here's the output]

Comment: Posting something that you can post as text as image isn't good.

Comment: Correctly formatting should probably help to identify the problem. Otherwise step through cour code with the debugger.

Comment: You did out-of-range access in `swap(arr[i],arr[i+1]);` Correct the logic properly.

Answer (score 2):

```
for(int i=1;i<n;i++)
    if(i%2!=0)
        swap(arr[i],arr[i+1]);
```

`n` is the size of `arr`. If `n` is even, on the last iteration of this `for` loop `i` will `n-1`, or odd, and this will end up swapping `arr[n-1]` with `arr[n]`, which is undefined behavior because, of course, there is no `arr[n]`.

This is where your random value comes from. Fortunately, it looks like you're managing to skate by without blowing up your stack, entirely.